# Multiple File Select in IE9 and Passing FileReference Data to Javascript

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, file-upload, filereference

So, Ive created a HTML5 XHR multi file uploader using javascript and jquery. Now I want to be able to offer a flash based fall back for browsers who only allow the selection of one file at a time (like Internet Explorer).

My question is, can I get flash to pass any of the raw file data over to javascript?

If I cannot get at the raw file data through an External Interface call, is there anyway I can give javascript enough information from flash for it to get the file data itself?

Failing all of this, what is the best way of offering multiple file selection in IE9?

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to pass `ByteArray` through `ExternalInterface`.

See http://ria.dzone.com/articles/javascript-flash